# Google plus web share button not sharing dynamic og tags

Tags: php, google-plus

I am trying to share some events using google plus share button. The problem I am facing is when I try to share a particular event by using the og tags where the content are hard-coded
for eg :

```
<meta property="og:title"  content="My Title">
<meta property="og:image" content="Awesome event">
<meta property="og:description" content="http://exqlusiv.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/tomorrowland-2012-video-live-sets-aftermovie.png">
```

And then use the code given at https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/ to share it, Its properly working but the problem is when I pass a variables to the content of the og tags like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description?>" />
```

The google share button do not detect the tags and not able to share the content properly. I am really stuck at this..

Any suggestion,

Thank You.

Comment: You may have to use htmlspecialchars at tags to prevent mistakes ..
Else your code is OK

Comment: Thanks for the reply but It did't work :(

Comment: Is your HTML code valide?

Comment: The variable `$image` contains the domain? Because otherwise will not work. FAIL: `<meta property="og:image" content="/img/name.jpg" />` CORRECTLY: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.com/img/name.jpg" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have verified, both by visiting the page directly and by use of the [Google Rich Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) that the data is correctly being filled in. And while Google sharing does usually recognize og data, you may also want to consider adding [Schema.org microdata](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) which Google seems to be better at handling.

Comment: Although I'm encountering the same problem (description doesn't populate) even when Schema.org data is present, as in `<meta itemprop="description" content="text text" />`.

Comment: @TopherHunt - You should probably create your own question with as many details and examples as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For Google+, append `?v=random_string` to the URL.
If you are using this idea with Facebook share, make sure that the `og:url` param in the response matches the URL you are sharing.

For Facebook, you can also force recrawl by making a post request to https://graph.facebook.com with

```
{id: url,
scrape: true}
```